# sed + cut line before ";" seperator

Tags: sed

how to perform by sed in order to print the line until ";" character

```
    echo "NUMBER   =   3247  FULL DUPLEX ; speed=343 434 " | sed .....
```

need the following output

NUMBER   =   3247  FULL DUPLEX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use awk for this?
i.e.

> echo "Number=3247 ; speed=343 434 " |
>   awk {'print $1'}

And if you really need the " in front, use

> echo "Number=3247 ; speed=343 434 " | awk {'print "\"" $1'}

EDIT:
After feedback (see comments below), here the correct version with sed:

> echo "NUMBER = 3247 FULL DUPLEX ;
>   speed=343 434 " | sed 's/\;.*//g'

Comment: not good because  Number   =    3247 (i have apaces)

Comment: see please my update in the question

Comment: OK you're right. How about sed 's\; .*//g' then?

Comment: echo "NUMBER   =   3247  FULL DUPLEX ; speed=343 434 " | sed 's/\; .*//g'  (need to add "/" after "s"

Comment: you can fix your answer according to your right remark so I will vote for you

Comment: another remark must be like this del the space in the sed:  sed 's/\;.*//g'

Comment: OK, glad it worked. And sorry about the typos!

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk` with `-F` to specify the field delimiter:

```
echo "NUMBER   =   3247  FULL DUPLEX ; speed=343 434 " | awk -F\; '{print $1;}'
```

Note that the semicolon is excaped with a backslash so that your shell won't misinterpret the semicolon as the end of the command.